# How to find the value of $ \sum_{n=0}^{1947} \left(\frac 1{2^n+ \sqrt{2^{1947}}} \right) $

Tags: sequences-and-series

I've no clue where to start from. I tried writing down a few terms to find out a pattern but didn't notice any. Any help would be appreciated! :)

Comment: $$\frac{1}{2^n + \sqrt{2^{1947}}} + \frac{1}{2^{1947-n} + \sqrt{2^{1947}}} =\;?$$

Comment: $$\frac{1}{2^n + \sqrt{2^{1947}}} + \frac{1}{2^{1947-n} + \sqrt{2^{1947}}} =
\frac{\sqrt{2^{1947}}}{\sqrt{2^{1947}}(2^n + \sqrt{2^{1947}})} + \frac{2^n}{\sqrt{2^{1947}}^2 + 2^n\sqrt{2^{1947}}}\\ =
\frac{\sqrt{2^{1947}}}{\sqrt{2^{1947}}(2^n + \sqrt{2^{1947}})} + \frac{2^n}{\sqrt{2^{1947}}(\sqrt{2^{1947}} + 2^n)} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2^{1947}}}
$$ Is that obvious now?